# How to use await in JUnit cleanup?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, junit

In my cleanup function I would like to clear Firebase Realtime Database (emulator).. but to be sure it has succeeded before it goes to the next test, I have to call await..

```
@After
fun cleanup() {
   ...
   instance.reference.setValue(null).await()
}
```

However, the cleanup function can not be suspend function.. so how could I achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: You could [use `runBlocking { }`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html). Depending on how the rest of your test class is set up, you might have access to test-specific variants of that (e.g., `runBlockingTest {}`), though I'm not sure those are available in an `@After` function.

Comment: Oh, i should brush up my kotlin a little bit.. this is exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually delete nodes and records after query for them, but I guess you can remove the top default root node

Get the reference

```
      MyFireBaseReference firebaseDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

then Delete the db or root node

```
      firebaseDbRef.removeValue();
```

---

A sample, please adapt to your needs.. documentation help from [Kotlin for you](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine)

```
  fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope

  launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
    
    println("Blocking and cleaning up DB!") // print after delay

      // get your DB reference
       MyFireBaseReference firebaseDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

      // then Delete the db or root nod
      firebaseDbRef.removeValue();

 }
 println("Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed
}
```